# how to dynamically change the appearence of html page produced in servlet

Tags: java, html, css, jsp, servlets

I know how Servlets are dynamically produce html pages, but how can we wite a servlet that makes the corresponding CSS file at the same time the html file is being created?
I mean how can we dynamically change the appearence of our html page?

Answer (score 0):

`htpp:/server/text.html` and `http://server/scripts/style.css` are from server point of view almost the same (need set correct header Content-type).

The other question is how to dynamically change appearance of page after loading (some JS/AJAX required)

Servlet can produce style (css) sheet text is the same way, like html (tagged text)